Avoid Accessing Somaxconn in Go/Golang
I'm trying to build a reverse proxy server that will run on an Android device. I was hoping to use Go because I can get a .aar file/archive that I can call from an app. The issue I'm running into is that any Go server, and even a lightweight reverse proxy I wrote all end up using a library that when run on Android keeps trying to access somaxconn (which is forbidden if you don't root your device first). Has anyone else been successful in this sort of a project? Are there any go libraries that wouldn't require access to somaxconn?
